# How to create a Netsuite customer search using the custom field as the criteria using the java api?

Tags: java, web-services, netsuite

I am trying to find customers in Netsuite by using a custom id that has been populated. I have some code written and it isn't getting the customer as a result. Instead I am getting no records back.  What am I doing wrong?

```
 public SearchResult searchCustomerbyExternalId(String externalID) throws RemoteException {
      CustomerSearch customerSrch = new CustomerSearch();
      CustomerSearchBasic customerSrchBsc = new CustomerSearchBasic();

      SearchStringCustomField custentity_externalid =  new SearchStringCustomField();
      custentity_externalid.setInternalId("1015");
      custentity_externalid.setSearchValue(externalID);
      custentity_externalid.setOperator(SearchStringFieldOperator.is);

  SearchCustomFieldList searchCustomFieldList = new SearchCustomFieldList();
      SearchCustomField[] SearchCustomFieldArray = {custentity_externalid};
      searchCustomFieldList.setCustomField(SearchCustomFieldArray);
      customerSrchBsc.setCustomFieldList(searchCustomFieldList);
      customerSrch.setBasic(customerSrchBsc);


      SearchResult searchResult = _service.search(customerSrch);
```

Comment: Never mind this code works as is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind this code works as is..